# Magento 2.2 Overriding template file

Tags: theme, overrides, magento2.2.4

I'm trying to override theme files in my custom theme based on the blank theme.

I managed to override the css with a custom css file. So i know my path correct. This path is:

```
<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

When i try to override the header.phtml nothing changes. I tried both urls:

```
<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/template/html/header.phtml
<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
```

Both files are not picked up by the compiler or whatever blocks the rendering.

I'm in developer mode and I'm using the Bitnami magento 2 from google cloud launcher.

Am I missing something badly here?

Comment: can you check : https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-override-default-theme-template-files/

Comment: Are you override file in App->design or in your custom module?

Comment: @PrashantPatel My path is exactly the same as the one stated in the tutorial: app/design/frontend/Wavelabs/afterparty/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

Comment: @ChiragPatel i'm using app->design

Comment: May be it is possible to already override in other module or somewhere. otherwise if your folder structure and path is right then it must reflect.

Comment: @ChiragPatel it is a fresh installation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some suggestions:

Even in developer mode cache can be turned on, so in this case you should run `bin/magento cache:flush` after you make changes or turn it off.

Sometimes you need to click `Flush Static Files` button in `admin->sytem->cache management`, as it seems like `bin/magento cache:flush` doesn't do this.

I am new to magento but as i understand magento doesn't override templates, it extends them instead so maybe you have your changes in markup but you dont see them in browser.

Comment: THANK YOU. I managed to fix the issue. I flushed the static files, removed everything under view_preprocessed and did bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy. Weird that i had to do this even in developer mode... Even after that it sometimes takes 2 flushes before it appears in my browser...

Comment: Just noticed that you use Bitnami, as far as i remember it has opcache turned on, so you better check it in php.ini file and turn off for develop purposes (use search in file by string opcache.enable= it should be opcache.enable=0 or commented out).